# How to Run an event while another event is running in wxWidgets GUI?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I created one GUI having two buttons. one is start button and the other is stop button. when start is pressed the program will execute in the background and the gui will freeze. I couldn't control the window anymore. even a mouse click is not responding. the stop button is for stopping the program. since the window is not responding as it is running the program i cant press stop. what is the possible solution? .please help

Comment: Don't run your costly operation in the main thread. It's not "in the background".

Comment: I am new to wxWidgets. i have no idea about the threads and how it is working..can you please elaborate?

Comment: @SarathSankar, please check the `thread` sample and the documentation on wxThread. If you will have more questions don't hesitate to ask either here or on the wx-forum.

Comment: can anyone demonstrate me how we use thread here. i am new to programming. i couldn't understand some jargon.

Answer (score 1):

A *thread* is sort of a *subprogram* inside your program. When the application starts it runs in the *main thread*. You can create many other threads; all of them (the main one included) share the application memory space (for example, same global vars in scope).

There are two kind of threads: "detached" and "joinable". *detached* threads delete themselves when they finish, think of them as "fire and forget". Conversely, *joinable* threads are deleted by yourself, only after they have completed their job.

In wxWidgets all GUI is executed in the main thread. Calling a GUI function from another thread is a nightmare, don't do it.

Your case is a typical situation. The "start" button launches a thread to do some job. If you want to cancel this job you push the "stop" button.

How to instruct the thread to cancel its job?

While you can use [wxCondition](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_condition.html), you can also set a flag on your own. The working thread reads at some moment this flag (it's not *automagic*, you must code it) and stops or continue depending on its value. Don't forget to use a [wxMutex](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_mutex.html) before accesing the flag to protect it from another thread changing it at the same time.

Also, threads can post messages to the main thread event-loop. This way you can tell the main thread that your worker thread has finished its job.

Threads require more attention when you're coding them. You must avoid some situations such as:

- "dead lock": two threads wait one for each other, none finishes.
- "race condition": several threads try to change a shared value at the same
  time.

More on [wxWidgets docs](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/group__group__class__threading.html) and thread sample.

Finally, C++11 has `std::thread` and other related friends (mutexes, semaphores, etc). It's your choice to use it instead of wxWidgets classes.